# House Plant identification (Not bromeliad)

Tags: identification

Can someone please help me identify the smaller plant in the photo? It sprouted all of a sudden, and I want to be sure it isn't harming the larger bromeliad(?) plant.

(I'm not sure if the main plant is a bromeliad, but that was what I was told when I inherited it)

[image: Image of two leafy green plants of unknown origin]

Edit: Here is the best picture I could get of the acorn

[image: Picture of an acorn]

Comment: Has this pot spent some time outside? It would appear that somone planted an acorn - usual suspects being squirrels.

Comment: Gently excavate and you will know if it’s a oak, most of the acorn will still be there

Comment: I used some soil from my potted plants outside, and confirmed its an acorn... So now I need to figure out how to replant it into a seperate pot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That appears to be an oak tree. It's a little too young to tell for sure whether it's in the white oak or black oak group.

Comment: Yup, I found the acorn after I did some careful digging! Do I need to do anything special to avoid killing it while replanting?

Comment: It'll have a tap root, so I suggest working from the outside of the pot, using a relatively flexible spatula, if possible, to gently excavate the soil down to the bottom of the pot while protecting the roots as best you can. The tap root may be a bit tangled in the bromeliad roots as well. Alternatively, unpot everything in a single root ball and work with the oak that way, then repot the bromeliad.